# How to find rows with duplicate values using pd.duplicated() and a date within +- 2 days Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a pandas dataframe such as:

```
       number     GENDER  DOB          Code
0     500401081      M 1994-08-01        AP
1     500401094      F 1998-05-04        CB
2     500401081      M 1994-08-03        AP
3     500401096      M 1998-05-06        AP
```

I want all rows that have the same number, GENDER, Code, and a DOB within 2 days of each other. So for example I would get a table returned like this:

```
   number     GENDER    DOB             Code
0     500401081      M 1994-08-01        AP
2     500401081      M 1994-08-03        AP
```

I have started out by using the duplicated() function to get all the duplicates of number, gender, and Code but am unable to come up with a solution to add the the +- two days.

```
df_dup = df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=["number","GENDER","Code"],keep=False)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the data by "DOB", compute then difference between successive "DOB" per group and construct a mask if the difference is lower of equal 2 days:

```
# group per number/GENDER
group = df.groupby(['number', 'GENDER']).ngroup()

# compute first mask
mask = df.sort_values(by='DOB').groupby(group)['DOB'].diff().le('2D')

# retrieve other duplicate value (the one before that matched in "mask")
duplicates = mask|mask.groupby(group).shift(-1)

# subset dataframe
df[duplicates]
```

output:

```
      number GENDER        DOB Code
0  500401081      M 1994-08-01   AP
2  500401081      M 1994-08-03   AP
```